TensorBoard HParams not showing accuracy metrics for hyperparameter tuning
I am working on hyperparameter tuning in TensorFlow and have set up an experiment using the HParams plugin in TensorBoard to log different configurations. My models are being trained with variations in dropout and learning rate, and I'm logging these parameters along with the model's accuracy. However, when I open TensorBoard and navigate to the HParams dashboard, the accuracy metrics associated with each trial are not displayed. The table shows the hyperparameters correctly, but the 'Accuracy' column is empty, even though my code compiles the model with 'accuracy' as a metric and uses the hp.KerasCallback for logging. I've verified that the models are training correctly, and other TensorBoard functionalities like the Scalars dashboard are showing the accuracy trends over epochs. I'm looking for assistance in understanding why the accuracy isn't showing up in the HParams table and how to fix this issue.
Picture: Missing Values in Accuracy Column
My Code for Hyperparameter Tuning with TensorBoard's HParams:
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api as hp
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

# Define hyperparameters
HP_DROPOUT = hp.HParam('dropout', hp.Discrete([0.2, 0.3, 0.4]))
HP_LEARNING_RATE = hp.HParam('learning_rate', hp.Discrete([1e-2, 1e-3]))

# Set up logging
log_dir = './tensorboard/nn_1'
with tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir).as_default():
    hp.hparams_config(
        hparams=[HP_DROPOUT, HP_LEARNING_RATE],
        metrics=[hp.Metric('accuracy', display_name='Accuracy')]
    )

# Training function
def train_test_model(hparams, session_num):
    model_name = f"model_1_session_{session_num}"
    print(f"Training {model_name} with hyperparameters {hparams}...")
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu'),
        Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT]),
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu'),
        Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT]),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=f'{log_dir}/{model_name}')
    hparams_callback = hp.KerasCallback(writer=f'{log_dir}/{model_name}', hparams=hparams)

    model.fit(
        x_train_reshaped, y_train_,
        epochs=3,
        validation_data=(x_val_reshaped, y_val),
        callbacks=[hparams_callback, tensorboard_callback]
    )

# Run the training for each set of hyperparameters
session_num = 0
for dropout_rate in HP_DROPOUT.domain.values:
    for learning_rate in HP_LEARNING_RATE.domain.values:
        hparams = {
            HP_DROPOUT: dropout_rate,
            HP_LEARNING_RATE: learning_rate,
        }
        train_test_model(hparams, session_num)
        session_num += 1



Thanks @SubbuVidyaSekar, but unfortunatly I can still not see the values of the accuracy column. I now added a picture to my question.

I followed the example in the link attached to the comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66595678
and the thing that made the difference for me was adding 'epoch_' before my metric names which I assume is because that mimics how they are typically represented in tensorboard (for the benefit of the hparams callback):
Edit: According to the same source, you may also need to add the group argument to specify "train" or "validation"
metrics=[hp.Metric('epoch_accuracy', group='validation', display_name='Accuracy')]

